# What is the rule with using a comma before 'as well' when it is the last two words in a sentence

Tags: punctuation

What is the rule with using a comma before *as well* when they are the last two words in a sentence? For example:

> Sam pitches for the middle school team and plays various positions for the varsity as well.

Comment: I see no need for a comma there.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK is right: there's no need. But you could use a comma if you wanted to set the "as well" off from the rest of the sentence and give it a bit more weight.

Answer (score 4):

This is a matter of style, so you should consult your style guide.  I prefer *The Chicago Manual of Style*.  A brief search doesn't reveal their guidelines for "as well," but [here](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Commas/faq0004.html)'s their take on the synonym "too."

> Use commas with *too* only when you want to emphasize an abrupt change
>   of thought[.]

Since the last two words in a sentence cannot constitute any change of thought, I think we may infer that a comma is not called for.

Answer (score -1):

If the word "too" or "also" is used at the end of a sentence, a comma is always placed beforehand. Since the phrase "as well" means the same as those two words, a comma must also be placed beforehand.